# Firebase chat message is not working

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to run Firebase chat message sample app, but I am getting error due to fire base lib.

The below lib which I have used on my application and referral link

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/firebase/real-time-android-chat-application-using-firebase-tutorial/

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sliderlayout.rrd.com.firebasechatmessaging, PID: 22131
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sliderlayout.rrd.com.firebasechatmessaging/sliderlayout.rrd.com.firebasechatmessaging.Register}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android classes not found. Are you using the firebase-client-android artifact?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android classes not found. Are you using the firebase-client-android artifact?
        at com.firebase.client.core.Context.setAndroidContext(Context.java:66)
        at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setAndroidContext(Firebase.java:974)
        at sliderlayout.rrd.com.firebasechatmessaging.Register.onCreate(Register.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android classes not found. Are
>   you using the firebase-client-android artifact?

because It happens because this version:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

You can use one of these:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.0'
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: thanks..while using above lib, I could not able to import import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

Comment: Firebase.setAndroidContext(this); need to import this firebase lib.. but I could not import..after importing successfully, i can run the app. other wise i can not